# Is it guaranteed that an RST packet will be sent when a process terminates?

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, network-programming, winsock

If I have a process with a connected socket, and I terminate this process, then Windows will cause an RST packet to be sent.

Is it guaranteed (is it documented somewhere) that an RST packet will always be sent when a process terminates, or could a FIN packet be sent instead?

Comment: The RST is a response to "unsolicited" traffic. This traffic was intended for the now non-existent process. The TCP stack will respond with a RST to such traffic. It doesn't "initiate" a RST due to process termination.

Comment: Do you have a citation for your claim that Windows will cause a RST packet to be sent?

Comment: What packet are you going to get if the remote server loses power?  Or if a backhoe cuts its internet connection?

Comment: @David Schwartz I captured the RST packet in Wireshark. But I'm not sure if this is always the case (and this is why I'm asking!). Note that the send buffer was empty when I terminated the process (unlike what I've read elsewhere that if the send buffer is not empty then an RST packet will be sent).

Answer (score 3):

TCP is not supposed to send an RST packet when a connection is closed. To close a connection, TCP goes through the following states on the client side:

1. Send a FIN packet. This action will change TCP state to `FIN_WAIT_1`.
2. In `FIN_WAIT_1`, TCP waits for an acknowledgement (ACK) from the server.
3. Once the acknowledgement is received, TCP enters `FIN_WAIT_2`.
4. In `FIN_WAIT_2`, TCP waits for a `FIN` packet from the server
5. Once `FIN` arrives, the client sends an `ACK` and enters `TIME_WAIT`
6. `TIME_WAIT` is exited after a while (typically, 30 secs. or 1 minute). The purpose of this state is to make it possible to resend the final `ACK` to the server in case it was lost.

There is no RST packet anywhere. RST is used to respond to unexpected traffic, **not** to close a connection.

For example, if you send a TCP packet to port 80, and the server is not running an HTTP server (and assuming the packet makes all the way to the server and is not blocked / ignored), then an RST reply is sent back to the client.

Comment: CLOSE_WAIT is not timed out. You're thinking of TIME_WAIT. Very confused, and mostly irrelevant.

Comment: @EJP Yes, you're right. I updated the answer. I honestly don't think that makes the whole answer "very confused", and most definitely it's not irrelevant. Clearly, the OP doesn't know how a TCP connection is closed, a simple yes/no answer would be of little use. At best, a comment is enough - a downvote is, in my opinion, utterly unnecessary. Do you really think that *this answer is not useful*?

Comment: Hmmm.  This looks like it describes a graceful socket shutdown.  If I remember rightly, isn't a non-graceful shutdown somewhat different?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes, it's different, depending on what happened to the receiving side. If the receiving process crashed or was killed for any reason, `send()` will return `ECONNRESET`. At the network level, either the receiver replies with `RST` packets (if the host is still alive), or won't reply at all.

Comment: "RST is used to respond to unexpected traffic, not to close a connection" When an RST packet is sent in response to closing a process, it is sent to tell the other end that I am gone, if an RST packet is not sent then the other end would still think that it is connected to me.

Comment: @paul The other end wouldn't think it was connected because a packet with the FIN flag set would tell it that it wasn't.

Comment: @David Schwartz Yes, a FIN packet indicates disconnection. But so does an RST packet (when the other end receives an RST packet, it will assume that I am gone).

Comment: @paul Right, so this comment is incorrect, "*if an RST packet is not sent then the other end would still think that it is connected to me*". The other end could tell that you're disconnected even if no RST is sent because a FIN could be sent.

Comment: @David Schwartz How will the other end receive a FIN packet if Windows does not send a FIN packet on process termination, but rather it sends an RST packet?!

Comment: @David Schwartz I think we have a misunderstanding here. When I said: "if an RST packet is not sent then the other end would still think that it is connected to me", I was only talking about process termination and not in general. So if on process termination Windows does not send an RST packet, then the other end would still think that it is connected to me.

Comment: @paul That's still wrong, because if Windows sends a FIN packet, the other end would not think it was connected to you. So sending a RST packet is not required to tell the other end that the connection is closed.

Comment: @paul We all agree the connection is closed. The question is whether Windows sends a RST packet. And clearly that's not required, because a FIN packet would do as well. The question is whether Windows is *guaranteed* to send a RST packet.

Comment: "if Windows sends a FIN packet, the other end would not think it was connected to you" What do you mean? If Windows sends a FIN packet to the other end, this will tell the other end that I am gone, and hence the other end was indeed connected to me before receiving the FIN packet! Note that I am talking about the application level (so when I say the other end receives a FIN packet, this means `recv()` returns `0`).

Comment: I really don't understand why would Windows send an RST packet to close a connection. RST packets are not sent spontaneously, they are sent in response to unexpected traffic (which could be coming in for a socket that wasn't properly closed), so, in principle, if the sender keeps the socket open but doesn't send anything, there will be no RST. On the other hand, FIN packets can be sent anytime to request connection termination. If Windows sends an RST when a connection is closed, that makes no sense to me. But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Try, for example, closing a connection before reading all the data the other side sent.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: If there is pending data to be sent when the process is killed, very likely the RST is the result of the "unsolicited" ACK of the previous data packet.

Comment: @jxh Notice he said pending data to be *read*, not *sent*. It actually makes sense to send RST in this case, because if you didn't read it yet, it's as if it arrived after the socket was closed.

Comment: Your answer is mostly about the states entered via FIN. Not useful.  The question is about RST.

Comment: @EJP No, the answer explains what happens when a TCP  connection is properly terminated, showing that RST is not involved.